# Episerver block for login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, episerver

I am new to episerver cms, I need to insert "login block" on top right corner of my home page and Front-end user should be able to login to the application. So I have created “LoginBlock”, ”LoginBlockController” and a class “LoginFormPostbackData”. Then I inserted the block on my page. Please find the code below

```
 [ContentType(DisplayName = "LoginBlock", GUID = "42103d00-abbe-44e8-bfc2-c07a543cac86", Description = "")]
public class LoginBlock : BlockData
{

    [CultureSpecific]
    [Display(
             Name = "Heading",
             Description = "Add a heading.",
             GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
             Order = 1)]
    public virtual String Heading { get; set; } 

    [Display(
      Name = "LoginForm", Description = "Login Form",
      GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
      Order = 2)]
    public virtual LoginFormPostbackData LoginPostbackData { get; set; } = new LoginFormPostbackData();
}

public class LoginBlockController : BlockController<LoginBlock>
{
    public override ActionResult Index(LoginBlock currentBlock)
    {
        return PartialView(currentBlock);
    }
}
 public class LoginFormPostbackData
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Please find the partial view of the block.

```
    <div>       
    <h2>@Html.PropertyFor(x => x.Heading)</h2>

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.Username, new { @class = "sr-only" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.Username, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.Password, new { @class = "sr-only" })
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

When I Try to run this application I am getting below error

> Type 'EpiserverSite1.Models.ViewModels.LoginFormPostbackData' could not be mapped to a PropertyDefinitionType
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: EPiServer.Core.TypeMismatchException: Type 'EpiserverSite1.Models.ViewModels.LoginFormPostbackData' could not be mapped to a PropertyDefinitionType

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`LoginFormPostbackData` isn't an Episerver property type. That is why it's complaining, it's essentially saying `LoginFormPostbackData` cannot be mapped to an Episerver property type.

You don't need a property for the form data, though. You could however use `LoginFormPostbackData` as a *view model* for your partial view, and possibly as a parameter type for your login controller to make it easier to receive the data from the form.